# WSL: Cannot run executables with dot slash ./ in the path

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

One of my collegues has the following problem in WSL (bash) where paths with dot slash do not work:

../filename.exe -> runs fine, gives output, exit code 0

./../filename.exe -> no output, exit code 1

This two commands should be equivalent right? I do not understand how one could work when the other does not. I checked that there were not any aliases called "." or something like that.

Doing the same in cygwin causes no issues...

**EDIT**

I can execute the same executable in WSL without any issues regardless of the path

Comment: From the viewpoint of invocation, they are equivalent, and I'm sure you don't see any difference if your replace `filename.exe` by something inncoent, such as a script in your parent directory, which you wrote yourself and know what it is doing. However, if the rogue programmer who wrote `filename.exe`, decided to look into `argv[0]` and behave differently on whatever he finds there, the behaviour might indeed be differnent. Shoot the programmer in this case.

Comment: @user1934428, thanks for answering.
 On my own machine also running WSL I can run the same executable without any issues... So I do not think it is something like using argv[0]. Or if it is it is quite esoteric because then its the combination of the ./ and the rest of the path.

Comment: Is the current directory a Windows or Linux directory ?

Comment: @Philippe It is on a mounted drive in WSL (/mnt/d/.../.../filename.exe)

Comment: From the viewpoint of the shell, the prefix of the `./` does not make any difference on a relative path . the very same executable will be run. You can verify it by yourself by running `stat` on either path. The only difference is that when the executable is invoked, it will place the path under which it was invoked, in the first argument of the executable. As I said - try it by yourself by substituting the executable by a bash script which you can trace by `set -x`.

Comment: Can you create a directory like `/tmp/dir1`, then copy filename.exe to `/tmp`, and run your 2 commands from `/tmp/dir1`

Comment: moving the file to /tmp/ did not change the behaviour. It still does not run when the paths looks like ./../tmp/filename.exe